# Using standard shells to build a custom app-specific shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell, zsh

I am wondering if it's possible to use standard shells e.g. `bash` or `zsh` with alternative profile and alternative history files to handle specific commands.

The motivation for doing this comes from using applications such as taskwarrior or timewarrior which make me type in a lot of commands that I don't want to interfere with history files of my "standard" use. This conflicts mainly with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> functionality.

Ideally, I would like to carry on with my standard shell and ignore all `task` and `timew` but open another shell (with some options and modifiers) which will source a different profile and use an alternative history file.

This will create an experience similar to interactive modes of various interpreters e.g. `ipython`, `gnuplot`.

Please let me know if you have any ideas.

Comment: (FWIW, my vote was not "off-topic" but "too broad" -- many of the folks interested in this kind of functionality actually just want libreadline, and eliminating shell-builtin functionality to the point where one has the equivalent of `rlwrap` -- providing history expansion but almost nothing else -- is a larger discussion than fits into a reasonable StackOverflow question).

Comment: I agree that the question the way I posed it may seem too broad, but Tony gave me an answer I was looking for. Does it make sense to rewrite the question to make it less broad?

Comment: I'd certainly vote to reopen in that case (caveat being that I was one vote of five, so the ultimate decision would depend on others' positions as well).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that isn't difficult at all. `bash -rcfile <filename>` will run the file `<filename>` instead of your usual rc file. Then in that file set the shell variable `HISTFILE` to a custom history file.